# How to send and read Messages over Signal with android app?

Tags: java, android, signals

I'm searching for a solution to send a Message (with my app) over Signal. And then receive it (with my app) and do further work. (e g show the location which has been send on a map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [signal-service-java](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-service-java) library, which comes from the developers of Signal.

It is sort of low level, so you can use instead [signal-cli](https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli), which is an upgraded version of it, and which you can use to write your code faster and easier.